# How to create copy of an object that is not connected to the original one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing something in my javascript code which I call it a bug but I believe it is technically a feature! So I have a json entity, I create a new one and equalize it to the first one. Now, any change that I perform on the second one, will be affected on the original one as well!

Here is the JSfiddle of simple example I have created: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2736/

given the code:

```
$scope.a = {
    name: "mike",
    age: 10
};

$scope.b = $scope.a;

$scope.b.name = "john";
```

shouldn't a.name be "mike" and only b.name become "john"? why does it happen to both of them?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: You don't have a "json entity", by the way. You have an object, plain and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely not a bug. You have assigned to `$scope.b` by reference. Since, `$scope.b` changes, so will `$scope.a`.

You should use `angular.copy` for different references.

```
$scope.b = angular.copy($scope.a);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ts0dd4qu/)